# How to prevent git from escapes "git-root" in Jenkins workspace?

Tags: git, jenkins

I keep Jenkins' configuration versioned under Git. Sometimes a job fails and git escaping from workspace looking for git-root. This is normal behavior of Git.

How can I prevent this behavior in Jenkins? I'm thinking about chrooting Jenkins' jobs, and I have to check this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/chroot+Plugin). But I have some tools and configuration outside Jenkins installation directory.

Comment: I did not enough time to check the plugin but I think that exporting environment variable GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES will be enough:

```export GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES=/var/lib/jenkins```